# php - Regular expression to validate this string

Tags: php, regex

What can be the regex to validate the string as below

0000-XXXX-XXXX

four digits at start then hyphen then 4 alphabets then hyphen and then 4 alphabets again.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show it to us.

Comment: @AD7six i meant first 4 digits, then four alphabets and then four again alhpabets

Comment: read a bit on http://www.regular-expressions.info/ then try something and then, if you have issues, tell us what didn't work. This isn't a "gimme teh codez" forum.

Comment: @Alyas and I meant try something and come back with an attempt instead of just sitting with your expectant hands out waiting for someone to do it for you. It's not like your question is so unique that it hasn't been asked before.

Comment: okay, i have created something /[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}/ I tested and it's working fine, is it okay or any more efficient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string="1234-ABCD-EFGH";

preg_match("~[0-9]{4}-[A-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{4}~", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

This code will output the $matches array that contains the match information.

`preg_match` will return `true` or `false` depending on whether the string matched.

If you prefer to also match lower case characters, use this one:

```
preg_match("~[0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z]{4}-[A-Za-z]{4}~", $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Though i created the solution as stated in question's comment, but as your solution is exact same as mine so accepting your answer :)